# Change Date Format in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, date, formatdatetime

**I've got this basic code :**

```
var currentDate:Date = new Date()
   var tommorow:Date = new Date()
   var day3:Date = new Date()
   var day4:Date = new Date()

currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate());
tommorow.setDate(tommorow.getDate()+1);
day3.setDate(day3.getDate()+2);
day4.setDate(day4.getDate()+3);
```

**If I do :**

```
trace(day4);
```

It returns : `Tue Sep 1 18:16:12 GMT+1100 2015`

How can I format this date in order to return this : `"Tuesday 1 september 2015"` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code works. you can copy this:

```
var today:Date=new Date();
var months:Array=["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","jul","Aug","Sep","Oct",
"Nov","Dec"];
//you can change them to your desired texts !

var days:Array=["Sat","Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri"];

var display:String=days[today.day]+" "+today.date+" "+months[today.month]+" "+today.fullYear;
trace(display);
```

now if you want to display the date of three days later , modify the `today` date.

I H☻ P E this helps.

Comment: Hm, why re-invent the wheel? Why not use `DateTimeFormatter`, which does this without hard-coded English values?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/globalization/DateTimeFormatter.html) with a [custom format pattern](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/globalization/DateTimeFormatter.html#setDateTimePattern%28%29):

```
var formatter:DateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatter(LocaleID.DEFAULT);
formatter.setDateTimePattern("EEEE d MMMM yyyy");
trace(formatter.format(new Date())); // ex: "Saturday 29 August 2015"
```

Comment: Yes your answer is better, I didn't even heared of `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: It was added in Flash Player 10.1, before that for years your answer was the only option, did it myself more times than I can count. :)